# How can I make an element take up the width of the window inside of the width of its parent?

Tags: html, css

I need to edit this #block only
Finally I need to show the table in full screen with width 100%

How can I make the div#block to get outside the 2 parent divs row & container?

```
<html>
<head><style>
.container{
    max-width: 80%;
}

.row{
    max-width: 90%;
}

#block{
    width: 100%; //I need to edit this block only - To show the table in full screen with width 100%
}
</style></head>
<body>

<center>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="block">
            <table border="1" width="100%">
            <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `position: absolute`

```css
.container {
    max-width: 80%;
}
.row {
    max-width: 90%;
}
#block {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<center>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="block">
                <table border="1" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Hello</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</center>
```

Comment: Your code works only with a page having a few few css, otherwise I get conflict with position: absolute; cuz my template is having more than 10,000 lines css

Comment: I want to see all relative code to help you more or at least an example that contains the scenario you describe :)

Comment: http://expo-craft.com/software/web/perfectionusa/index.php --- use Inspect element for top menu and search for #block_top_menu and try to make the menu full width :)

Comment: The problem is that you have set `max-width: 85%;` to the parent container. You can set it to 100% and then you handle each element separately.

Comment: I know that i can do that... but I prefer to get the menu only full width easier than re-changing all the website blocks to 85% separately :)

Answer (score 2):

You can increase the `width` to `140%` and use `margin-left: -20%`  to align it.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 80%;
}
.row {
  max-width: 90%;
}
#block {
  width: 140%;
  margin-left: -20%;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="block">
        <table border="1" width="100%">
          <tr>
            <td>Hello</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</center>
```

Comment: thnx but its' not an accurate solution for a complicated css code with more than 10,000 css lines

Comment: @Ahmed - Do you mean the space before and after `#block`?

Comment: @Ahmed - If you want an accurate solution, I can write some JavaScript code for that.